# Can I harm my iPhone if I damaged my lightning cable chip or scratched the contacts?

Tags: iphone, hardware, lightning

I was using a Dremel to make the aluminum shell on a new lightning cable (long, braided) fit through the hole in my iPhone 6S+ case.

The aluminum shell got extremely hot. The cable seems to charge fine (didn't try data transfer), but I'm neurotic enough to worry that maybe the chip is somewhat damaged and something bad could happen in the future...Neurotic, right?

Also, I scraped some of the contacts (it was my first time using the Dremel!), which I'm guessing is no big deal either...?

Thanks :)

Comment: In my opinion, better safe than sorry. You can buy an AmazonBasics lightning cable from Amazon for just $6.

Comment: yeah but this is a nice, long, braided cable and I don't want to waste or have more boxes shipped...(speaking of neurotic :) )

Comment: Good point. What you really don't want is a replacement iPhone, that uses far more resources. Of course, you CAN keep using that cord, just the heat + lack of ventilation may pose a fire risk. And the damaged contacts may gradually (or even quickly!) slow/halt charging. And could slowly be harming your iPhone's charging point (though you're definitely not going to break your iPhone totally). If you choose to replace your iPhone, you can get a pre-braided cable, like this Anker one (here: http://amzn.to/29jo5xk) for $9 (on sale right now).